# In PHP,array concept

Tags: php

I have two arrays...I want to find the common element in the array.I want to find the unique values in array1 and unique values in array2....
Example:

```
Array1:"red,blue,green,violet"

Array2:"yellow,orange,violet,blue
```

Now i want to know how will i retrive

```
uniq_Arr1=>red,green

uniq_Arr2=>yellow,orange

common_Arr=>violet,blue
```

That is,From each array it sholud retrive the unique elements and the common elements...
Please guide me to know this...

Answer (score 10):

Use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to find common elements and [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to find the differences.

Here's my test code:

```
$array1 = array("red", "blue", "green", "violet");
$array2 = array("yellow", "orange", "violet", "blue");

$uniq_arr1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$uniq_arr2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
$common_arr = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Thanks..Just now i tried.....Can anyone explain me the same in two dimensional array,so that i could know still better.....

Comment: Not much more to be said, I think.

Comment: Play with the code for a bit, you will begin to understand how it works.